# How to unit-test a custom Validator with constructor-arg dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a custom validator like this (simplified for brevity):

```
//Custom Validator for my TaskDto. DTO annotated by @MyAnnotation
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotation, TaskDto> {

    private final MyRestClient restClient;//Constructor-arg dependency

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TaskDto dto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        Map<String, Variable> taskVariables = restClient.getTaskVariables(dto.getTaskId());
        return !taskVariables.isEmpty();
   }
}
...

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyValidatorTest {

    private Validator validator;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }


    @Test
    public void testTaskDto(){
       TaskDto taskDto = taskDto.builder().setTaskId(1).build();
       validator.validate(taskDto);
    }
}
```

If I run the Test I get

```
HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: 
....
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:44)
```

As I understand - because there are no default constructor.
If I change constructor-arg dependency to

```
 @Autowired MyRestClient restClient
```

- I get NPE, because `restClient` is NULL.

Is there any way to use constructor-arg dependency and inject a mocked `MyRestClient` into my custom validator?

Comment: Mock `MyRestClient`. If you are running a spring test, autowiring `MyValidator` should give you an instance, which already depends on your mock. Otherwise just instantiate `MyValidator` manually with the mock.

Comment: Thanks. I can instantiate `MyValidator` manually with Mocked `MyRestClient`, but where should I get `ConstraintValidatorContext` for the `isValid()` ?

Comment: Anyway, I don't need `ConstraintValidatorContext` for test MyValidator logic. So it is a working solution, thanks

Comment: Provide mock for the method. `MyValidator` does not use the context, so you don't need to mock the methods, just a mock is enough.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to get the validator via spring injection into tests by using @SpringBootTest annotation (see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing))

Then you can just mock the restclient by adding this annotation to the test class:

```
@MockBean(MyRestClient.class)
```

You also dont need to init the validator by hand, but can just use

```
@Autowired
MyValidator myValidator;
```

in your test class

Comment: Thanks. Yep, I tried with @SpringBootTest but there are some problems with setting up the context and that  problems are somewhere out of my area of responsibility in this project. Also, I don`t want to set up context at all and use 'light-weight' test